# Wrapping C++ using ctypes: undefined symbol

Tags: c++, python, shared-libraries, ctypes, word-wrap

I am experimenting with wrapping C++ in order to use C++ functions in Python. Currently I am trying out ctypes and unfortunately, I have not yet been successful. For starters I have written a Hello World program in C++ and I am trying to call it from Python using ctypes. This is what I have done:

```
path_to_dir $ vim helloworld.cpp

1: #include <iostream>
2:
3: using namespace std;
4:
5: int main()
6: {
7:     cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
8:     return 0;
9: }

path_to_dir $ gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,hello_module -o hello_module.so -fPIC helloworld.cpp
path_to_dir $ vim helloworld.py

1: import ctypes
2:
3: libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("path_to_dir/hello_module.so")
4: 
5: libc.main()

path_to_dir $ python helloworld.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld.py", line 3, in <module>
    libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("/home/carlos/Workspace/Freestyle/Wrapping_C++/ctypes/hello_module.so")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/carlos/Workspace/Freestyle/Wrapping_C++/ctypes/hello_module.so: undefined symbol: _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
```

The traceback mentions something about an undefined symbol however I do not know why I get this error and how to solve it. I also tried standard C++ libraries instead of writing one like this on my own. That worked out fine. Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should compile with `g++` instead of `gcc`. 
`gcc` does not link the binary with c++ libraries.